# Htaccess rewrite issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I tried to use seo friendly url for my website, my target was to rewrite `product/131/ABCDEFGH` to `productpage.php?id=131`

I achieved this now it rewrite path and open correct page

.htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^product/(([^/]*))/([^/]*)$ /cprrpc/productpage.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Now I got another problem which is something related to internal links, currently all images etc on this page are binded with relative path.

Now this will not work, because they all are searching in different path,

I open on another approach or to change htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URLs gets skewed on the rewritten URL structure as there's now two more directory levels. Instead of using relative URLs *to the current directory* use a **leading slash** for your resources OR you could use PHP to print the "root path" to your application in front of all your resources.

For example instead of using a relative URL (to the current directory):

`<img src="images/plus.png" />` (expands to *localhost/cprrpc/product/131/images/gplus.png*)

you could use a leading slash which makes the URL relative to the web root:

`<img src="/cprrpc/images/plus.png" />` (expands to *localhost/cprrpc/images/gplus.png*)

OR you could print the web root using PHP:

`<img src="<?php echo $WEB_ROOT ?>/images/plus.png" />` (expands to *localhost/cprrpc/images/gplus.png*)

Comment: but as I added these conditions, my original page is also not opening. may be I missed something?

Comment: Well these conditions would only fix resources existing in the location */product/xxx/yyy...*, but would not match anything else. Basically it would not affect your rewrite at all unless the file or directory already exists in your filesystem. Let's say you are trying to rewrite `product/131/ABCDEFGH` but you also have that exact file structure already (which I doubt), then the existing file/directory will be executed as normal.. but if you remove the conditions it works again?

Comment: sorry, your code has not lost my page, but still it is not opening the images

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/cprrpc/product/131/images/gplus.png

because this page images are relative to the main url which is cprprc/images/glus.png

Comment: Aha. You could use PHP to print the "root path" to your application behind all your resources instead of using relative URLs. For example instead of `<img src="/images/plus.png" />` (expands to *localhost/cprrpc/product/131/images/gplus.png*) you would have `<img src="<?php echo $WEB_ROOT ?>/images/plus.png" />` (expands to *localhost/cprrpc/images/gplus.png*)

Comment: ok.. thats the only way we can achieve it.  I need to rewrite all  internal links for this.

Comment: Wait something is not right lol. Does your resources start with a slash? Like so `/images/plus.png` or so `images/plus.png`?

Comment: although , i like both idea, i.e. use webroot or use absolute path.
but i have changed / to _ which will automatically fix my issue, Next time i will keep both suggestion in mind

Comment: I'm glad you got it resolved. I've updated my answer if you'd like to mark it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow apache to serve existing files from their real location:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^product/(([^/]*))/([^/]*)$ /cprrpc/productpage.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This means apache will ignore the rewrite if an image is requested..

Comment: but as I added these conditions, my original rewrite is also not opening. may be I missed something?

Comment: I missed off the ! negation

Comment: sorry, your code has not lost my page, but still it is not opening the images

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/cprrpc/product/131/images/gplus.png

because this page images are relative to the main url which is cprprc/images/glus.png

Comment: because you're using relative image paths, try using absolute paths:
/image/here.jpg

Comment: although , i like your idea, i.e. use absolute path. but i have changed / to _ which will automatically redirect to correct path if i have not used absolute path, Next time i will keep your suggestion in mind